# AVPlayer keeping in memory when the video is in loop

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I need to put a player in loop, but why when I add the

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,object: nil, queue:nil){
 notification in
 videoPlayer.seek(to: KCMTimeZero)
 videoplayer.play()
 }
}
```

My view stay in memory when i give dismiss in my viewController.
How i reproduce a video my memory goes to increasing all every time that I open the ViewController

Whithout this code it is removed with sucess.

I don't know what I have to do

Can you help me please?

Comment: Did you manage in some way any `deinit` or `viewDidDisappear` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three issues with your code:

1. By default, references are passed as strong into a block. To make sure they are not retained, use `weak` or `unowned`:

   ```
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemdidPlayToEndTime,object: nil, queue:nil){
   [weak videoPlayer] notification in
   videoPlayer?.seek(to: KCMTimeZero)
   videoplayer?.play()
   }
   ```
2. Since iOS 9, observers do not need to be removed from the `NotificationCenter` **unless** you are using block observers (which you are). You should store the reference to the observer which is returned from `NotificationCenter.addObserver:forName:object:queue:usingBlock:`:

   ```
   self.observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(...)
   ```

and in `viewWillDissappear`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self.observer)
```

(alternatively, you could use a selector instead, as Chan Jing Hong pointed out; in that case, removing the observer is no longer necessary but might be needed depending on your app's logic)

3. The way you are registering for `NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemdidPlayToEndTime`, you will be notified whenever the playback of **any** `AVPlayerItem` reaches the end. To avoid potential problems, listen to the notification on the currently played item (by replacing `object:nil` with `object: playerItem`)

Comment: Hi friend, your solution of to put as weak works perfectly, I am very grate to you. 
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should set self as the observer when adding to NotificationCenter.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemDidReachedEnd(_:)), name: Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
```

This way, in your `viewWillDisappear`, you can do `removeObserver()`

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: `self` (the `UIViewController`) is not registered as the observer